# Is there a way to disable fakeredis once it's loaded?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm working with some code that uses the fakeredis gem for specs, but whenever I run those specs from a REPL, fakeredis stays around and commands like `Redis.new` will just give me fakeredis.  I need to be able to disable it to be able to access the real redis store again.

Is there a way to disable/enable it in the REPL?

Comment: Changing your environment to "development" should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions, either remove the fakeredis memory class:

```
Redis::Connection.drivers.delete_if {|d| d == Redis::Connection::Memory }
```

or append the Ruby adapter again:

```
Redis::Connection.drivers << Redis::Connection::Ruby
```

Source: https://github.com/guilleiguaran/fakeredis/issues/63